# How to get date representing the first day of a month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date

I need functionality in a script that will enable me to insert dates into a table.

What SQL do I need to insert a date of the format

```
01/08/2010 00:00:00
```

where the date is the first day of the current month. What do I need to change order that I can specify the month value? Thanks

Comment: Late question for clarification, but this is really ambiguous. Are you inserting the formatted date to a string-character column (`103` for the `CONVERT` function) or do you just need a `date`?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The best and easiest way to do this is to use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Just replace GETDATE() with whatever date you need.

Comment: Clever but not terribly obvious. Be sure to comment this in your code to prevent the inevitable head scratching from anyone else who reads your code in the future.

Comment: Very clever. It's unusual thinking, but in Databases, date and time actually HAVE a beginning! So you can actually think of a point-in-time as an absolute value.

Comment: This is fantastic. Was only able to understand after a bit of pondering. Thanks.

Comment: So what this does is: (1) Get the number of months between the current date and 0. (2) Add that number of months back to 0. This sets the day part to 1 (first day of the month).

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly - Look here for an explaination: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665119/dateaddmonth-datediffmonth-0-getdate-0-can-someone-explain-me-this

Comment: I like this, but my implementation would spell it out a little further:
`SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0);`
One less scratch of the head!

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer works, and may be faster, but SQL 2012 and above have a more easily understood method:

```
SELECT cast(format(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-01') as Date)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select cast(cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as char(4)) 
+ '/' 
+ cast(datepart(month,getdate()) as char(2))
+ '/01' as datetime)
```

Comment: Equivalent to `CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 111) + '01'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple way to do this (using SQL 2012 or later)

```
datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1)
```

you can also easily get the last day of the month using

```
eomonth(getdate())
```

Comment: Because I have fat fingers. I upvoted one of your other answers to cancel things out.

Comment: @IanKemp: better to make a small edit and then change your vote.

Comment: @IanKemp: it has been edited since then, you can change your vote now.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DATEADD(day,1-DATEpart(day, GETDATE()),GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

i think normally converts string to MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss, you would need to use 08/01/2010 00:00:00

Sorry, misunderstood the question, looking to see if you can change the order for strings.

This may be what you want:

```
declare @test as date

select @test = CONVERT(date, '01/08/2010 00:00:00', 103)
select convert(varchar(15), @test, 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-query-to-find-first-and-last-day-of-current-month/).  This will return as string, but you can modify as needed to return your datetime data type.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This worked perfectly.  I actually added a Case statement.  Thanks for the post:

```
SELECT Case(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2012 you can use the [`eomonth` built-in function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx), which is intended for getting the end of the month but can also be used to get the start as so:

```
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(<date>, -1))
```

If you need the result as a `datetime` etc., just [`cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it:

```
select cast(dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(<date>, -1)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get First Day of Last Month

```
Select ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Get Last Day of Last Month

```
Select LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH));
```

Comment: `ADDDATE` is a MySQL-command, Question is about MS SQL-Server

Answer (score -1):

select last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1))+1 from dual;

Comment: What SQL variant is this? OP tagged question with [tag:sql-server], which implies T-SQL, but this isn't.

Answer (score -2):

... in Powershell you can do something like this:

Get-Date (get-Date ((Get-Date) ) -format MM.yyyy)

... for the last month do this:

Get-Date (get-Date ((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) ) -format MM.yyyy)

... or for custom Date do this:

Get-Date (get-Date ((Get-Date  12.01.2013) ) -format MM.yyyy)

I`m sure there`s something like this possible ...

Gruß

Answer (score -2):

Very simple piece of code to do this

$date - extract(day from $date) + 1

two ways to do this:

1. my_date - extract(day from my_date) + 1
2. '2014/01/21' - extract(day from '2014/01/21') + 1

Comment: This is neither ANSI nor T-SQL.  Tag [tag:sql-server] implies MS SQL.