# DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) Can someone explain me this

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Can someone explain me this.

Answer (score 49):

this will give you the first of the month for a given date

inner select 
`select DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())` will give the number of months from 1900-01-01

here it is 1350

this will be add to 1900-01-01 , but only the months

`select DATEADD(MONTH,1350,0)` will give 2012-07-01 00:00:00.000

which is the start of the current month.

I think this is the most efficient way to find the starting of a month for any given date.

Answer (score 15):

The DateDiff function returns how many seconds, months, years - whatever interval you specify between the first date (here 0) and the second date (here the current date).

```
     DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2-14-2015')  --returns month. 0 is for 1/1/1900, and getdate is the current date 
     --(i used a set date bc dates will change as this post gets older).
     result: 1381
```

In my workings, I used the date of 2-14-2015 and it gave me 1381 number of months since 1/1/1900. I put 1381 into the dateadd function like so...

```
     select Dateadd(MONTH, 1381, 0)
     result: 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

Basically, it gets the first day of the whatever month is specified in the date of the innermost formula.

The code i was having to figure out went a step farther and subtracted 1 second from that result to get the last day of the month at 11:59:59 like so...

```
     select DATEADD(s, -1, '2015-02-01 00:00:00.000')
```

The Formula all put together looks like this:

```
     DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate())+1,0))
```

Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
The DATEDIFF will give you date diff in month from January 1 1900 to current date
AND 
The DATEADD will add (DATEDIFF) results months to your last parameter of DATEADD
```

Answer (score 2):

It's getting the start of the current month. It counts the number of months since January 1900, and adds on them to January 1 1900 to get the start of the current month

Comment: I always thought that setting the day to 1 will achieve the same result but is much easier?

Answer (score 1):

> The DATEADD function adds an interval to a date you specify. For
>   example, if the due dates of all  orders in the SalesOrderHeader table
>   slipped 3 days, you could obtain the new dates with the following
>   statement:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT DATEADD(day, 3, DueDate)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader;
GO
```

> The DATEDIFF function calculates the period of time in dateparts
>   between the second and first of two dates you specify. In other words,
>   it finds an interval between two dates. The result is a signed integer
>   value equal to date2 - date1 in date parts. The following query uses
>   the date November 30, 2001, and finds the number of days that elapsed
>   between DueDate and that date:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, DueDate, 'Nov 30 2001')
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader;
GO



SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '20051220', '20060101')
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '20051220', '20060101')
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '20051220', '20060101')
```