# Please explain me with one example for : DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6,0)

Tags: sql-server

Hello i reviewed this article.But i can not understand how it works?

[DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) Can someone explain me this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665119/dateaddmonth-datediffmonth-0-getdate-0-can-someone-explain-me-this)
Please explain me with one example for : DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6,0)

Comment: You've linked to an existing question, and that question has multiple answers. If the answers are unsatisfactory, please highlight *why*. Don't just demand new answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) Can someone explain me this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665119/dateaddmonth-datediffmonth-0-getdate-0-can-someone-explain-me-this)

Comment: why you guys do not understand that i already mentioned that this question is similar to that question but i did not understand clearly so i am asking it again.and you guys just gave me minus marking.so frustrated.

Comment: Because you've not explained *why* the existing answers are unsatisfactory. We don't know that, and you've not explained.

Comment: those answer did not understand by me.You can also see that there is a difference between my question and above question.So i am confused.

Answer (score 1):

The DATEADD() function adds or subtracts a specified time interval from a date.

```
DATEADD(datepart,number,date)
```

The DATEPART() function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

```
DATEPART(datepart,date)
```

The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

datepart can be

```
d-> day
m-> month
y-> year
```

your query can be split as below:-

```
select GETDATE()  --> returns Current date eg: 2016-01-12 01:07:35.453

select DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()) --> returns months between two dates, 0 is for  1/1/1900  ->1392
```

i.e you can re write it as:

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH,1/1/1900,GETDATE())
```

next:-

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6  --> substract 6 months again -> 1386
```

re-writing:-

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH,1/1/1900,GETDATE())-6
```

then:-

```
select DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6,0) -->add 1386 months to '1/1/1900'
```

re-writing as:-

```
select DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,1/1/1900,GETDATE())-6,1/1/1900)
```

in short your quwey is equivalent to

```
select DATEADD(MONTH,1386,1/1/1900)
```

Answer (score 0):

This part: `SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())`

Selecting number of month after `1900-01-01` so current month is `1392`

And with `SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1392-6,0)` you substracting 6 months from current month.

So you got output: `2015-07-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: This closely parallels the highest voted answer on the existing question the OP links to. If this answer "works" for the OP then it means the question should definitely be closed as a duplicate.