# Calculating this weeks date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to find out if there is a way in which I can calculate this weeks date range.

For instance

```
Monday -    2016-11-21
Tuesday -   2016-11-22
Wednesday - 2016-11-23
```

and so on an so forth.

If some one can help me out with the syntax and calculation that would be great.

Comment: Please keep in mind that there is more than one definition for a "week". Depending on your need, you might want to keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi Jens, What do you mean exactly? If i can avoid future issues i will want to.

Comment: Depending on region the way a week is defined can change. In some regions a week starts on Monday, others on Sunday. Also handling weeks in a year, these implementations could differ, especially around the beginning and end of a year. Week 1 doesn't necessarily start with the first of January, it could even still be a part of last year's week. This is a pretty common BI problem.

Comment: Ah i understand what you are saying. Fortunately this is only for a report for a small UK based team, so region's will not play an effect into this. However the year part.... that could cause an issue, but i will have to see how that pans out in a month and half. Thank you for the advise though Jens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with them in their own columns then you can do something like this;

```
SELECT
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0) Last_Monday
,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 2, GETDATE()) - 1, 1) Last_Tuesday
,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 2, GETDATE()) - 1, 2) Last_Wednesday
,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 2, GETDATE()) - 1, 3) Last_Thursday
```

Result;

```
Last_Monday             Last_Tuesday            Last_Wednesday          Last_Thursday
2016-11-14 00:00:00.000 2016-11-15 00:00:00.000 2016-11-16 00:00:00.000 2016-11-17 00:00:00.000
```

If you need it in rows then just union the result;

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0) Date_Field, 'Last_Monday' Day_Name
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 2, GETDATE()) - 1, 1), 'Last_Tuesday'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 2, GETDATE()) - 1, 2), 'Last_Wednesday'
UNION 
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 2, GETDATE()) - 1, 3), 'Last_Thursday'
```

Result;

```
Date_Field                  Day_Name
2016-11-14 00:00:00.000     Last_Monday
2016-11-15 00:00:00.000     Last_Tuesday
2016-11-16 00:00:00.000     Last_Wednesday
2016-11-17 00:00:00.000     Last_Thursday
```

Take a read here for a good explanation of how this works;

[DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) Can someone explain me this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665119/dateaddmonth-datediffmonth-0-getdate-0-can-someone-explain-me-this)

Comment: Hi Rich, that has worked a right treat. I can use that for what i need. Might sound like a silly question...... but could you break it down so that i can understand why this has worked?

Comment: I've just linked to a post that explains it pretty well, let me know if that doesn't clear it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE = '2016-11-21'

;WITH CTE (_Date)
AS (
    SELECT @StartDT

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, _Date)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE _Date < DATEADD(DAY, 6, @StartDT)
    )
SELECT _Date
    ,DATENAME(W, _Date)
FROM CTE
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the starting and ending date of the week and iterate trough those dates:

```
Declare @startDay   datetime,
        @endDay     datetime,
        @iterDate   datetime

Set @startDay = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()) / 7 * 7, 0) --Starting day of this week
Set @endDay = dateadd(day, 7, @startDay)

Set @iterDate = @startDay

Declare @tmpResults Table (Date datetime, DayName varchar(20))

While (@iterDate < @endDay)

Begin
    Insert into @tmpResults (Date, DayName)
    Values (@iterDate, datename(weekday, @iterDate))

    Set @iterDate = dateadd(day, 1, @iterDate)
End

select Date, DayName From @tmpResults
```

Results:

[image]