# Query with errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have a problem with a query, my table looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He2ZJ.png).**

*As a result of the query I want the beginning of the month of the current day knowing that if it is January begins 01/01/2017. We start from the last days of the month, we know that the beginning of the month is the end of the previous month plus one.
My query is as follows:*

```
select * 
from (select top 11 case when replace(convert(varchar, EndMonth, 111), '/','-') = replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/','-') then replace(convert(varchar, EndMonth, 111), '/','-') else replace(convert(varchar, DATEADD(day,1,EndMonth), 111), '/','-') end as inicio  
from EndMonths 
where EndMonth >= convert(date,getdate()) 
and Year between  DATEPART (year, getdate()) 
and ( (DATEPART (year, getdate())+1)) or id = (select top 1 id-1 from P_materials.dbo.dia_cierre_fiscal where Year= DATEPART (year, getdate()) and Month(EndMonth) = Month(getdate()) order by EndMonth desc) 
order by EndMonth)a 
union 
select case when GETDATE()<=(select EndMonth from EndMonths where Year=2017 and NameMonth='Jenuary') then convert(varchar,YEAR(GETDATE()))+'-01-01' else '' end
```

*it was running before it was February once it was February it did not give me the same result.*

Comment: Is it    NameMonth='Jenuary'

Comment: isn't this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503742/how-to-get-date-representing-the-first-day-of-a-month

Comment: sorry, not that it happens that the beginning of the month is the EndMonth of the previous month plus a day, for example if the end of January is 03/02/2017 the beginning of February will be 04/02/2017.
It should be clarified that they are fiscal months of a company

Comment: As an example if the end of January is 03/02/2017 the beginning of February will be 04/02/2017.
It should be clarified that they are fiscal months of a company

Comment: It would make this _much_ easier if the table also contained the start of month. Do you have that option? This kind of thing is often modelled in a 'calendar table'

Comment: @JoseAntonioEsparza, how many days/weeks are in each fiscal month?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small repro of your data, and a query that transforms it into a start date/end date pair:

```
WITH YourTable AS 
(
SELECT Label,D
FROM (
VALUES 
('Jan',CAST('2017-02-03' AS DATE)),
('Feb',CAST('2017-03-03' AS DATE)),
('Mar',CAST('2017-03-31' AS DATE)),
('Apr',CAST('2017-05-05' AS DATE)),
('May',CAST('2017-06-02' AS DATE))
) T(Label, D)
) 

SELECT ED.Label,
(SELECT DATEADD(d,1,MAX(D)) FROM YourTable WHERE D < ED.D) StartDate,
ED.D EndDate
FROM 
YourTable ED
```

To make use of it you just plug in the date you want:

```
WITH YourTable AS 
(
SELECT Label,D
FROM (
VALUES 
('Jan',CAST('2017-02-03' AS DATE)),
('Feb',CAST('2017-03-03' AS DATE)),
('Mar',CAST('2017-03-31' AS DATE)),
('Apr',CAST('2017-05-05' AS DATE)),
('May',CAST('2017-06-02' AS DATE))
) T(Label, D)
) 

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ED.Label,
    (SELECT DATEADD(d,1,MAX(D)) FROM YourTable WHERE D < ED.D) StartDate,
    ED.D EndDate
    FROM 
    YourTable ED
) ATable
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Note for any future questions: screenshots are OK, but some actual SQL code (i.e. the values code that I have above) that allows us to quickly use your data makes things easier and faster for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you making this complicated?

```
select cast(datepart(m, getdate()) as varchar(2)) + '/1/'+ cast (datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar (4))
```

Comment: because these are fiscal months that do not start on the 1st

Answer (score -1):

You can get the first and last date of the month, based on a provided date as following:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE = '2017-02-01'

SELECT   DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@MyDate),MONTH(@MyDate),01) AS Start_Month
        ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@MyDate),MONTH(@MyDate) + 1,01)) AS End_Month
```

Comment: As an example if the end of January is 03/02/2017 the beginning of February will be 04/02/2017.
It should be clarified that they are fiscal months of a company